# gdal_rasterize is giving no data while converting a shapefile to raster

Tags: raster, shapefile, gdal, gdal-rasterize

I have used next command:

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 1 -tr 30 30 fire_2010.shp fireRaster2010.tif
```

to convert shapefile to raster. But I am getting no data in the raster. The same command works for another shapefile. The only difference I see is the polygons in this shapefile are small.

[image]

So, from the image it can be checked that **fireRaster2010** has 0 0 [no values]. The **fire2010** is a shapefile, and that is visible as blue colored patches.

here is the shapefile
[image]

here is the raster file- no data. The values 0 0 in the Layer Panel signifies that there is no data in the file. All the values are zero.
[image]

Comment: It could be an extent issue (please, see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely an extent issue.

> The values 0 0 in the Layer Panel signifies that there is no data in the file.

No, it does not. It only shows the values being used for coloring. You are using qgis, which, by default (at least for me), chooses default values for the style based on the 2% to 98% range of your data. I believe it does this to deal with outliers that could really skew the colors. But in this case, because your data is predominately 0 with only a few 1's, this range ends up being set as 0 0 for coloring purposes because the 1's are essentially being treated as outliers.

To check this you either need to manually set your color range to 0 1 in the properties for the layer, or you can use the identify tool (blue circle with an 'i' in it and a mouse cursor icon) to click individual pixels and see their values

Comment: Yes. You are exactly right. By using gdalinfo -hist <filename>,  the file shows the histogram of all its values. So, my file had data, but it was showing 0 0 in QGIS.  I sorted this out by changing the max value in QGIS.

Comment: Tip: You can change the behaviour settings to "Minimum/Maximum" in the **settings > options > rendering > raster > limits** if you find this gets annoying :-)

Answer (score 1):

For rasterizing in fire studies is convenient that you first get polygon for layer extent that contain all years.

In my case, I considered three years (1990-1992) for [Portugal case](http://www.icnf.pt/portal/florestas/dfci/inc/info-geo). That polygon at next image:

[image]

it has this extent:

```
xMin,yMin 82175,9600 : xMax,yMax 356140.00,572100.00
```

equivalent to:

```
-te 82175 9600 356140.00 572100.00
```

as parameter syntax of **gdal_rasterize** command.

Assuming the same raster resolution (-tr 30 30), my three **gdal_rasterize** commands are:

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 1 -te 82175 9600 356140.00 572100.00 -tr 30 30 fire_1990.shp fireRaster1990.tif
gdal_rasterize -burn 1 -te 82175 9600 356140.00 572100.00 -tr 30 30 fire_1991.shp fireRaster1991.tif
gdal_rasterize -burn 1 -te 82175 9600 356140.00 572100.00 -tr 30 30 fire_1992.shp fireRaster1992.tif
```

After running each one at the bash console, I loaded all resulting raster at Map View of QGIS. In the case of 1990 year, it can be observed (pseudocolor with two classes, Spectral ramp):

[image]

If I hide **fire_1990** shapefile, I got a similar behavior as in your case: small areas look as not rasterized but they were.

[image]

Zoom an arbitrary zone where this behavior occurs, it permit to corroborate that they really exist.

[image]

I think that in your case could be an extent issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot xunilk for your reply. But I guess, there is difference what you rasterized. The values you got after rasterizing are either 0 or 1. There is data. What I am getting is a blank file. All values are 0. I have put the separate images of my shapefile and raster file.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

On possible issue is that `-tr` specifies the resolution in the unit of the input's CRS, so if the input is in EPSG:4326 then `-tr 1 1` will produce a raster where each pixel correspond to 1 degree of latitude/longitude, which is most likely not what you want.

In your case you specified `-tr 30 30`. If the CRS of the shapefile has unit of meter and your feature are much smaller than 30 meters they will not show up.

Try `-tr 5 5` and see if that improves things.